# LibGDX and Sound Priorities

Tags: java, libgdx

According to a post I found, the `setPriority` of a `Sound` in LibGDX is not only a hint, but does nothing on desktop, and I can confirm this.

I really need priorities for sounds in my desktop game.

The first thing that comes to mind is to roll some kind of simple "sound system" with, say, a `PriorityQueue`, but I'm not quite sure of how I would implement it exactly, and I'd like to re-use code as much as possible... has anyone here perhaps rolled one that I could use?